# What's a 'null defined macro'?

Tags: objective-c, c-preprocessor

I'm learning objective-C and Cocoa. In the Apple tutorial I'm working through there's a side note that says:

> `IBOutlet` is a null-defined macro, which the C preprocessor removes at compile time.

I'm curious - what's a null-defined macro?

Answer (score 8):

```
#define IBOutlet
```

Whenever IBOutlet is used in program text, it will be replaced with nothing at all.

Answer (score 8):

FYI, in this particular case, the reason the `IBOutlet` even exists is simply so that Interface Builder can parse the source file and glean bits of understanding from it.  It's a clue (well, a bit stronger than a clue) that the variable preceded by `IBOutlet` should show up as an Outlet in Interface Builder when designing your UIs.

Answer (score 7):

A null-defined macro is a macro which will be replaced by nothing (will be removed) by the preprocessor. It's role is to give a hint about something in code, such as:

```
#define IN
#define OUT
#define INOUT

int myFunction(IN char *name, INOUT char *address, OUT char *phone);
```

This declaration suggests that `name` is a input variable for the function, `address` is both input and output, `phone` is an output variable.

Comment: That's really cute. Reminds me of Ada (obviously).

I prefer to prefix the parameter name with in or out. But same effect.

Comment: Same, except for lack of pollution of the namespace with crazy macros. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Also - if you're unsure how anything is defined - command double-click it and Xcode will open the definition in the original source file.

Answer (score 0):

Oh and while I'm at it. Option double click will (attempt to) open up the documentation for the double clicked symbol.

Comment: Why don't you merge the two answers and delete one?